# How to program in C# using SFML.NET?

Tags: c#, c++, sfml

I have an understanding of C++ and C#, I just don't understand how to use SFML.NET without any documentation. I know that the API is almost exactly the same, I just don't understand bindings fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is indeed similar. Have a look at the examples ([online here](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML.Net/tree/master/examples) or with the SDK). You should be able to figure it out quite easily once your have read the C++ tutorials and those examples.